# When does APC remove old entries?

Tags: php, garbage-collection, apc

I'm struggling to find any logic in the way APC clears up its old entries.
Especially with user entries, I notice the fragmentation quickly increasing to unexpected levels.

Although apc.ttl and apc.user_ttl are set at 3600, I notice a LOT of old entries in the APC cache which are not getting cleared. I have repeatedly increased the size of the memory for APC, but it only makes it last a little longer before reaching 100% fragmentation.

So, why could this be happening? Actually I would consider this a bug in APC, it's just not normal behaviour. I would expect some APC process to clear out old entries from time to time.

Also, could it lead to the conclusion that it would be better to use another caching system for PHP, and only use APC as an opcode cache (where the lack of cleaning is less of a problem)?

Comment: Personally, I would use another caching mechanism for userdata, and only use APC for opcode caching - I've not encountered any problems with userdata caching on APC, but a distributed userdata cache such as memcache or redis gives scalability when its needed

Comment: All the APC functions have a time-to-live parameter, should'nt you be using that if you expect the values to be deleted after a certain time ?

Comment: @adeneo The ttl is used all the time, but cache entries created 1 day ago and valid for 5 minutes are still in the cache now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure old values are removed. You need to explicitly remove it.

I use a combination of APC and memcached in my applications. APC provides opcode caching as well as caches local data that is likely to remain unchanged (Like config files). All other objects are cached in memcached using some sort of a read through logic. (Gets cleared if data is changed)

When I do a new release, I restart APC (via apache or php if its a separate process). That will clear the APC cache and the config files will get reloaded shortly afterwards. I will restart memcached if the objects have changed significantly enough to cause issues if its loading old cache data.

Comment: Does memcached actually remove items that have expired?

Comment: Yes, memcached supports an expiration of 1 second to 24 hours. You will set the expiration you prefer when you store the data.

Comment: Memcached and APC remove expired items. But only when needed, which is when there's no more room left for a new entry. That's the garbage collector. Caching/expiring is working exactly the same way in both. The major difference is that Memcached doesn't fragment memory. And the expiration, for both, can be from 1 second to years, not 24h.